# Double-Buffering VB6 with BitBlt help

Tags: graphics, vb6, gdi

Edit: I updated version 2.  Now It's monochrome.  I tried to fix it by making sure to call `CreateCOmpatibleBitmap` with the window's DC rather than the memdc (as written), but it is still wrong :(

Below are 3 different simplified versions of functions I have written.  Version 1 works perfectly (but has flicker, obviously), version 2 does nothing, and version 3 fills the entire form with black.  What is wrong with version 2?  Scalemode is set to vbPixels.

Version 1:

```
Private Sub Form_Paint()
    Me.Cls
    DrawStuff Me.hDc
End Sub
```

Version 2 (new):

```
Private Sub Form_Paint()
    Me.Cls
    If m_HDCmem = 0 then
        m_HDC = GetDC(hwnd)
        m_HDCmem = CreateCompatibleDC(m_HDC)
        m_HBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(m_HDC, Me.ScaleWidth, Me.ScaleHeight)
        ReleaseDC Null, m_HDC
        SelectObject m_HDCmem, m_HBitmap
    End If
    DrawStuff m_HDCmem
    Debug.Print BitBlt(Me.hDc, 0, 0, Me.ScaleWidth, Me.ScaleHeight, m_HDCmem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY) 'During testing, this printed "1"
    Me.Refresh
End Sub
```

Version 3:

```
Private Sub Form_Paint()
    Me.Cls
    If m_HDC = 0 Then m_HDC = CreateCompatibleDC(Me.hDc)
    DrawStuff m_HDC
    BitBlt(Me.hDc, 0, 0, Me.ScaleWidth, Me.ScaleHeight, m_HDC, 0, 0, BLACKNESS) 'During testing, this printed "1"
    Me.Refresh
End Sub
```

Note: I stuck the code below in my resize function immediately before the call to paint.  It did not help, but I'm pretty sure I should leave it there:

```
If m_HDC <> 0 Then DeleteDC m_HDC
m_HDC = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

in Version 2 & 3 your call to CreateCompatibleDC() builds a monochrome drawing surface that is 1 pixel by 1 pixel. You need to call CreateCompatibleBitmap() somewhere in there.

see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa922550.aspx)

Comment: It's monocrhome, but working.  Apparently this issue is common, but the fix I saw did not help.